# How do I use the scala mongodb driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to use the scala mongodb driver.  I have set up a small test database and created the following program to count the entries in a collection.

```
import org.mongodb.scala._
object MongoTester extends App {
  val mc = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
  val db = mc.getDatabase("test")
  val nodes = db.getCollection("test")
  nodes.count().subscribe(
    (nodeCount: Long) => println("Count %d".format(nodeCount)),
    (error: Throwable) => println("Error"),
    () => println("Done")
  )
  println("Here\n")
  mc.close()
}
```

When I run it, it only works occasionally.  I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the way I handle the subscribe and close.  But I don't know how to fix it.

Here are the results when it doesn't work:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7541 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/IdeaProjects/MongoTest/target/scala-2.11/classes:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/bson/jars/bson-3.2.0.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-async/jars/mongodb-driver-async-3.2.0.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/jars/mongodb-driver-core-3.2.0.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb.scala/mongo-scala-bson_2.11/jars/mongo-scala-bson_2.11-1.1.0.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb.scala/mongo-scala-driver_2.11/jars/mongo-scala-driver_2.11-1.1.0.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.7.jar:/Users/simonshapiro/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain MongoTester
Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:3}] to localhost:27017
Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=13074668}
Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017
Here

Jan 25, 2016 6:45:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If this is (and I'm assuming it is) a toy example try put a `Thread.sleep` for a second before you do `mc.close()`. You might just be closing the connection to the client before your count operation publishes its results.

Comment: Many thanks!  I added the one second delay and now it is working consistently so I can concentrate on learning the other available methods and features.